# XCode : Cannot print object in console when debuging

Tags: ios, xcode

Without any reason, Xcode show an error when i whan ton print using the debuger console :

```
(lldb) po self
warning: Swift error in scratch context: error: failed to load module 'XXX'
.
Shared Swift state for XXX.app has developed fatal errors and is being discarded.
REPL definitions and persistent names/types will be lost.

error: expression failed to parse:
unknown error
```

It's an iOS project with cocoapods. I'm on an M1 pro chip.

Any idea ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finaly found ! I have a personal static framework that cause the problem. I follow [this tutorial](https://andresalla.com/en/fixing-virtual-filesystem-overlay-file-all-product-headers-yaml-not-found-error/) and it works !

1- In debug on a breakpoint of your project, type the command `image list`.

2- Search for the framework and retrieve the UUID at the beginning of the line (example of UUID 664A127D-C264-3415-8515-E0DB99B606C8")

3- Open a terminal and run the command

```
mdfind -0 "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == 664A127D-C264-3415-8515-E0DB99B606C8" | xargs -0 rm -rf --
```

4- Delete the contents of the `DerivedData` folder:

`rm -rf $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

5- The debugger should work :)